# SQL Server cross join for comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am new to sql programming. I wrote this procedure for side-by-side comparison of columns for each [cg code]. I want to fetch rows from the left table even if the match is not found (see where condition). Whenever a match is not found, I want to insert a row from the left table into cig_attributes_comparison table with the right columns being NULL. The reason why i used a cursor is, the table has large number of rows. As the cross join is going to fetch large number of rows, i used a cursor to process one [cg code] at a time.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @ProcessingCG nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @cg_count INT;
SET @cg_count = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE [PDDMN_ACCESS].dbo.cig_attributes_comparison;

DECLARE distinctcg CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT DISTINCT [CG Code] 
    FROM [PDDMN_ACCESS].dbo.V_PDDMN_PMUSA_RRpt_FDA905SE_CigAttributes 

OPEN distinctcg;    

-- Fetch the first CG from the cursor to process   
FETCH NEXT FROM distinctcg INTO @ProcessingCG

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    -- count the number of cgs processed
    SET @cg_count = @cg_count + 1;

    -- Commit after processing every 100 CGCODES
    IF @cg_count% 100 = 0 
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        COMMIT;
    END

    INSERT INTO cig_attributes_comparison ([temporary se number left],
                            [cg code left], [component left], [subcomponent left], 
                            [table usage left], [function name left], 
                            [function uom left], [function ll left],
                            [function tgt left], [function ul left],
                            [sort order left],
                            [submission type left],
                            [component material left],
                            [component material group left],
                            [temporary se number right],
                            [cg code right],
                            [component right],
                            [subcomponent right],
                            [table usage right],
                            [function name right],
                            [function uom right],
                            [function ll right],
                            [function tgt right],
                            [function ul right],
                            [sort order right],
                            [submission type right],
                            [component material right],
                            [component material group right])
        SELECT
            lft.[temporary se number], lft.[cg code], lft.[component],
            lft.[subcomponent], lft.[table usage],
            lft.[function name],
            lft.[function uom],
            lft.[function ll],
            lft.[function tgt],
            lft.[function ul],
            lft.[sort order],
            lft.[submission type],
            lft.[componentmaterial],
            lft.[componentmaterialgroup],
            rgt.[temporary se number],
            rgt.[cg code],
            rgt.[component],
            rgt.[subcomponent],
            rgt.[table usage],
            rgt.[function name],
            rgt.[function uom],
            rgt.[function ll],
            rgt.[function tgt],
            rgt.[function ul],
            rgt.[sort order],
            rgt.[submission type],
            rgt.[componentmaterial],
            rgt.[componentmaterialgroup]
        FROM
            [PDDMN_ACCESS].dbo.V_PDDMN_PMUSA_RRpt_FDA905SE_CigAttributes lft, 
            [PDDMN_ACCESS].dbo.V_PDDMN_PMUSA_RRpt_FDA905SE_CigAttributes rgt
        WHERE
            lft.[cg code] = @ProcessingCG 
            AND lft.[cg code] <> rgt.[cg code] 
            AND ISNULL(lft.component, ' ') = ISNULL(rgt.component, ' ') 
            AND ISNULL(lft.subcomponent, ' ') = ISNULL(rgt.subcomponent, ' ') 
            AND ISNULL(lft.[table usage], ' ') = ISNULL(rgt.[table usage], ' ') 
            AND ISNULL(lft.[function name], ' ') = ISNULL(rgt.[function name],' ') 
            AND ISNULL(lft.[function uom], ' ') = ISNULL(rgt.[function uom], ' ')

    FETCH NEXT FROM distinctcg into @ProcessingCG
END  

CLOSE distinctcg;  
DEALLOCATE distinctcg;  

END
```

Comment: The ANSI-92 style join has been around now for close to 30 years. Time to update your join syntax. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins And you do NOT need a cursor to insert data. This can and should be changed to be a single insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a cursor, which in this case would be overkill to use. The join will give you everything you need from the left table and nulls on the right where matches aren't found. Just specify in the `WHERE` clasue that the right results `IS NULL` to filter for the non-existing ones to include in your insert.

An example of how you could potentially do this is below:

```sql
INSERT INTO comparison_table

SELECT
    -- specify your needed columns here, 
    -- only using * for illustration purposes
    *
FROM
    table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.shared_column = table2.shared_column
WHERE
    table2.table_id IS NULL;
```

Please look into learning more about SQL JOINS and ANSI SQL, here are some helpful links to aid you:

- [SQL Tutorial W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) is an easy to follow and light weight set of tutorials explaining SQL
- [Brent Ozar training](https://www.brentozar.com/training/) has a great blog on SQL Server and some free training material
- [SQLTutorial.ORG](https://www.sqltutorial.org/) has good explanations on SQL